# I want to store a list of pair of values <val 1, val2> and sort the pair according to val2?

Tags: java

I have a pair of values `<integer1, integer2>`. Which data structure should I use to store them so   that I can sort the list according to integer2 and access them through indexing afterwards?

Comment: Sorry, but that's nowhere near enough information for someone to give you a useful recommendation. Separately: Do *you* have any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: i have a list of integer pairs like:
<2, 3>
<4, 1>
<2, 2>
<3, 5>
.. 
How should i store them so that i can sort them according to the second value:
<4, 1>
<2, 2>
<2, 3>
<3, 5>

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I'll swing:

Create a class with fields for your two values, then either use a `List` (if the number of elements varies) or an array (if it doesn't) where that class is the element type. Both lists and arrays give you access by index, and either can be sorted according to properties of the elements.

See:

- [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
- [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) for sorting lists
- [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) for sorting arrays

Answer (score 0):

you haven't gave enough information however if you'd like to match one value to another you should use `MAP`
for example if your first value is country and second value is capital city.
you can load into your `MAP` all values of (country,capital city) and if you will give a country the `MAP` will return the capital city.
you can read more here: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: i don't want a <key, value> pair. I want a <value,value> pair.

Comment: Create a class which has two attributes: value1 and value2. Then create a list of instances of this class.

Comment: How do i sort that array of class according to value 2?

Comment: the simplest way is to define to arrays and coordinate between them. a[0] to b[0], a[1] to b[1] etc....

Comment: @Madeyedexter: google for "sort array of objects in Java" and you'll have hundreds of answers.